# High CPU with WPF on Atom netbook

Tags: c#, wpf, gpu

I'm writing an application with a highly stylized WPF interface (all default Windows UI chrome is gone and all controls have custom styles). The application runs great on the machine I'm developing on (Core i7 with NVidia 550M) at barely 1% CPU.  On a friend's brand new netbook (AMD Fusion C-50, Radeon HD 6250) it runs at maybe 1-2% CPU usage.  But then I took my wife's old netbook to test it on something weaker (an original Dell Mini 9, Atom N270, Intel 945 Express graphics) and run the same application and it runs at nearly 50% CPU! However, it drops to like 4-5% when the application is minimized, so I figure it's got to be the actual GUI that's causing the problem.

But I'm not really familiar with how WPF is rendered (I'm using the latest .NET 4.0 framework). Is it really THAT graphics intensive?  The GUI as it is, while stylized, doesn't really do much... just a progress bar that updates continuously and a couple of list animations that happen maybe every 3 minutes (it's a media app). But other than that, the GUI is fairly static.

Since I haven't given a lot of specifics of how the GUI was written I'm obviously not expecting an specifics on how to fix it, but I was hoping for some clarification as to how dependent the latest WPF is on having a relatively modern GPU (I admit, this GPU can barely handle an SD youtube video).  Is there a "minimum requirements" for WPF 4?  The application itself is really simplistic, so I'd hate for it to have really modern hardware requirements just because I used WPF.

Comment: Have you considered that the hardware is just crappy? The Atom processors are horribly slow. I've got an old AMD Athlon from 2001 that runs faster than a Z690. They're just not designed to do anything much beyond a bit of web browsing.

Comment: Have you tried profiling it to see where it's spending its time?  This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx

Comment: @Polynomial - I realize the CPU is crappy, I'm just concerned by the 25x CPU increase and wonder if it really is the CPU or just the GPU. CPU-wise it's doing VERY little.

Comment: @AdamHaile: Do you use AllowTransparency=True ? If so, try google something like: WPF AllowTransparency performance cpu

Comment: WPF uses the GPU extensively. It is possible that WPF or the graphs drivers fallback to CPU calculation on that netBook.

Comment: @AdamHaile - Keep in mind that the CPU gets utilised for GPU operations on an Atom processor. I'm relatively sure that this gets counted in with the CPU usage timers. This means that any work that would've been massively parallelized and offloaded on a standard GPU is now pushed through a very small number of pipelines and has to interrupt the CPU repeatedly to do the work.

Comment: @Steven - The Atom processors are both a CPU and GPU. The architecture is shared, so it's horribly slow when doing anything mildly intensive. Pushing the GPU also slows the CPU, and vice versa.

Comment: @Polynomial - Atom processors didn't have an on on-die GPU till the second generation... in the question, I stated that the CPU was an Atom N270 (First Gen) and it uses the Intel 945PM/GS Chipset. So, i'm probably even worse off :P

Answer (score 1):

By virtue of DirectX, video acceleration will be preferred with fallback to software rendering if for any reason that fails. Is your wife's machine XP? Given that you're using custom window chromes etcetera you may have set AllowsTransparency=true? If so, your app may be falling back to software rendering as a result.

Use WpfPerf to figure out whether it's being software rendered. Ensure you have XP SP3 and if still unresolved, try [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937106/en-us).

Comment: It's actually Windows 7 Starter edition (actually runs really well). Also, yes... definitely using AllowsTransparency. I wanted the app to have a very clean look with no borders. Didn't really realize that using that made much of a difference. I do need to test it out in XP though... was going to setup a VM to test it out tonight.

Comment: Testing in a VM might be a little misleading, depending on how well it supports hardware acceleration. I still suggest you check whether it's using hardware acceleration on your wife's machine - it might be falling back for other reasons.

Comment: So, I'm guessing that since the "SW IRTs per Frame" graph is full, but the "HW IRTs per Frame" is empty, means I'm in Software only mode?

Comment: Also, noticed in Visual Profiler, that while no one UI element is taking a significant amount of CPU, under "Application CPU Usage" it lists the "Rendering Thread" as using about 35% CPU.... so I'm guessing that's where it's all at, just rendering it in software?

Comment: @Adam: you can also set it to show a purple tint for any software-rendered elements. If your whole UI turns purple...

Comment: Ack :( ALL Purple on my dev machine (Nvidia 550M)...WTF?  I checked, and inside the application it reports Render Tier 2... so what gives? That makes no sense!!

Comment: Would it still be falling back to software if AllowsTransparency=true in Win7? If so, why?

Comment: @Adam: check this out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/06/22/software-rendering-usage-in-wpf.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if anything on the list affects me... Though, I think it's somehow machine specific at this point. Just tried it on another desktop that is actually older with a much older (but Tier 2) GPU and it renders hardware mode fine.  I'll have to check that reg key on my laptop... no idea how it would've been changed though.